# Python3: Delete line if begin with specific text

Tags: python-3.x

it's a first time i write, hope dont make mistakes (in case i'm sorry).

I am trying to delete a entire lines (from first word) text file using

> re.sub

but nothing.

This is code

```
import mysql.connector, os, sys, re, string
#read input file
fin = open("Data.txt", "rt")
#read file contents to string
data = fin.read()

#replace all occurrences of the required string
data = data.replace(',', '\r\n,')
......
data = data.replace('`:', '`:\r\nline_to_delete') # i use this to rewrite first word in the line i want delete


re.sub(r'^ line_to_delete .*\n?', '', data, flags=re.MULTILINE) #noone of this 2 lines seems to works
#re.sub('.line_to_delete.*\n?','',data) # but no errors

#close the input file
fin.close()

#open the input file in write mode
fin = open("DataModified.txt", "wt")
#overrite the input file with the resulting data
fin.write(data)
#close the file
fin.close()
```

thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 problems here :

- `re.sub` doesn't change the original string to the replaced version, it returns a new string, which you will have to store like you did with `data = data.replace()`, or else `data` itself will stay the same
- In your regex, you included 2 spaces on either side of `line_to_delete`. But when you replaced "`:" with just "\r\nline_to_delete", there is no space before it, so it would never match. (*Every character matters* in the regex - even the spaces, [this is a good site to check what your regex is matching](https://regexr.com/5q6jg))

Try this :

```py
import re
data = "a, b, c`:d, e`:f, g\ni`:j, k" #For example

data = data.replace(',', '\r\n,')
data = data.replace('`:', '`:\r\nline_to_delete')
print("Identified lines to delete - \n", data, '\n')

data = re.sub(r'^line_to_delete.*\n?', '', data, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(data)
```

Comment: about space you are right, was my test and i forget to delete when i posted. I tried with CCC instead of "line_to_delete" but with same result  Thank you for site. I check it now